# Is there any difference between "his role in X" and "his part in X"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, collocations

Is there any difference between below pair sentences ?

1. > He was suspended for his role in a sordid affair.
2. > He was suspended for his part in a sordid affair.
3. > It has a key role in X process.
4. > It has a key part in Y process.

I know, we usually use patterns like "play + role" and "take + part". Is there any significant point that we must be aware of it.

Comment: One can also "play the part", it's not unheard of in the theatre or moving pictures.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there is no long answer here - no, there is no difference between the two sentences for each example. They can both be used with the exact same meaning

Comment: It is unbelievable. As far as I know, there is  always an exception .. :). BTW, thanks

Comment: No exceptions with this one as hard as it may be to believe. If I was going to be picky, you might typically say 4 instead of 3, but there is still no difference between them. 1 and 2 are completely the same and would both be used equally